# typescript/node project: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm having an issue connecting to a mysql database which I'm running locally on my machine using a node server (also running locally).

### Background Info / Setup

My node project is using typescript, but I am running it by running `tsc` then `npm run start` (aka, not using ts-node)

I use typeORM to connect to the database running on my machine. Here is how i'm starting up the connection:

```ts
import {createConnections} from "typeorm";
import { runServer } from "./server";

async function startServer(): Promise<void> {

    console.log("Starting server...");
    runServer();

    try {
        await createConnections();
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

startServer();
```

typeORM in their documentation included that createConnections() will try to use default connections, or any connections defined in ormconfig.js, which I have done:

```js
// ormconfig.js
module.exports = [{
    "name": "MySQL Local DB",
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "test_user",
    "password": "12345",
    "database" "test_db",
    "entities": ["entities/*.js"],
    "logging": true
},
...
// more db connections defined here for sqlite and other db's
]
```

### The Issue

When I run `npm run start` I get this error:

```
ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'test_user'@'localhost' to database 'api'
```

To fix this issue I run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_db.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';` followed by `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

After I execute this line, I get a new error:

```
ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

To fix this one I've tried running `ALTER USER 'test_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '12345';` followed by `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` but I get the same error.

I've tried a different version of this, where I create the user with `mysql_native_password` set by default, then try connecting, get the "cannot connect to db 'test_db'" message, then Grant all privileges on that db, but then I get the "Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server" error.

### What I've tried:

- various combinations of `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES...` and `ALTER USER ... mysql_native_password`, with no success
- Doing a fresh install of mysql and running it as both a windows service and disabling run as service.
- Setting my security/authentication settings to Legacy in MySQL Server configuration

### What might be the issue, but I haven't tried

I have a mysql-init.txt file running whenever I run mysqld to start the server, but all I do in that one is set the password for the root user and tell it to run using mysql_native_password, so I don't think it should be causing the issue.

Sorry for the information dump. Hopefully its all useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly was the issue but I resolved the issue by modifying the file used in --init-file to look like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
CREATE USER 'test_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '12345';
GRANT ALL ON test_db.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

For some reason running this on server startup rather than running these queries manually by logging in as root ended up working.

If anyone knows why this worked, I'd greatly appreciate an explanation.